# Thymeleaf: "cannot find declaration to go to" error on Intelijj

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

I am making a project in which I am using Thymeleaf.

IDE is IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2 x64.

Intellij cannot recognize Thyemeleaf and I get following message when I am hovering over `th:each` "Cannot find declaration to go to".

In that file, I put following tag `<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">`.

**This is my pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>net.javaguides</groupId>
<artifactId>springboot-thymeleaf-crud-web-app</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>springboot-thymeleaf-crud-web-app</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot and thymeleaf</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Can someone tell me where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thymeleaf is only supported in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, not in the community edition. See https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html